# Is it a convention to have a minimal init.pp that class-scopes the module?

Tags: puppet

I've come across the following convention, the `init.pp` is as minimal as possible and looks like this for the example of a `java8` module in `modules/java8/init.pp`

```
import "*"

class java8 {
    include java8::java8
}
```

Then a `modules/java8/java8.pp` defines the actual rules/implementations:

```
class java8::java8 {
  # ...
}
```

Is this a convention, is it an old convention and deprecated? What would or is the rational behind this?

Comment: read https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html

Comment: @iamauser I don't see anything in that link that addresses this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that style as any widely-used convention, and I see only limited value to it.  Specifically, it appears to serve as a compromise between code organization interests and usage interests: it allows that every class of consequence will be defined in a manifest file named after it (including the delegate main class, `java8::java8`, in `modules/java8/manifests/java8.pp`), while providing a main class for the module with a one-segment qualified name (`java8`), so that users can simply

```
include 'java8'
```

I think it's fairly common nowadays to keep the main class small by making it delegate the details to other, private, classes inside the module, but I don't see much value in delegating to exactly *one* other class for (apparently) naming purposes alone.  I also think it's potentially confusing to have different classes with the same unqualified name (`java8`) in the same module.